# AntD Table navigate to other route on click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using React Router in the navigation component but i want to navigate to screen X from screen Y when the user clicks on a table element.
Before using antD i did this by using  this however does not work here.

```
    return {
      onClick: event => {
              
      },
   };
}
```

Comment: could you please show what you have tried? or how you table looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the react-routers `useHistory` hook

```js
const history = useHistory()
//...
// somewhere else in the code
onClick={() => history.push("/route")}
```